# R lubridate. What goes wrong?

Tags: r, lubridate, as.date

Tried to make a factor to date.

X:

```
Jul-15
Jul-15
Jul-15
Jul-15
Aug-16
```

I want to convert them to a date.

```
X <- as.Date(Xx, format="%b-%y")
```

Results in NA's.

This was my source for the code: https://www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/

Comment: Did u tried this: x <- as.Date(as.character(Xx, format = "%b-%y"))

Comment: Can you edit your question and include results of `dput(head(Xx))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as.Date is the base R function, as_date is the lubridate function, but this is not your problem

Without a day, you're not completely specifying the date completely. Unlike year, where R will fill in with the current year, this does not appear to happen for a missing day

As a workaround, run:

```
X <- as.Date(paste0(Xx,'-01'), format="%b-%y-%d")
```

Which will set the dates to be the first of the month

Answer (score 0):

The `yearmon` function from the `zoo` package will help you here.  Since you have `lubridate` as a tag on the question, we can then use `as_date` from the `lubridate` package to turn it into a date object. The base function `as.Date` will work as well.

```
library(zoo)  
library(lubridate)

as_date(as.yearmon(Xx, "%b-%y"))

[1] "2015-07-01" "2015-07-01" "2015-07-01" "2015-07-01" "2016-08-01"
```

If you want to leave them as yearmon class, you can just run:

```
 as.yearmon(Xx, "%b-%y")

[1] "Jul 2015" "Jul 2015" "Jul 2015" "Jul 2015" "Aug 2016"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a complete date, with day :

```
library(lubridate)
X <- "Jul-15"
X <- paste("01", X, sep="-")
dmy(X)
```